# Writing to vector beyond size causes panic

Tags: c++, stl

I have the following simple C++ program that uses the vector container from STL

```
  1
  2 #include <iostream>
  3 #include <vector>
  4
  5 using namespace std;
  6
  7 #define SIZE 10
  8
  9 int main()
 10 {
 11     vector<int> v(SIZE);
 12
 13     // for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
 14     // for (int i = 0; i < SIZE + 1; i++)
 15     for (int i = 0; i < SIZE + 2; i++)
 16         v[i] = i * i;
 17
 18     for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
 19         cout << v[i] << " ";
 20     cout << endl;
 21
 22     return 0;
 23 }
```

When I uncomment line (a), all is good.

When I enable line (b), I don't get an error/panic.  I am guessing this is because vector class dose not do bound checking, and the code is writing to memory on stack it should not be.  Right?

However, when I enable line (c), I get a panic.  Why am I getting a panic, when the code is writing to an additional int on the stack?   But more oddly, the backtrace says the panic occurred on line 22?  I figured the panic should have happened on line 16.  Can someone please help me understand.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fd1494fe475 in *__GI_raise (sig=<optimized out>) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
#1  0x00007fd1495016f0 in *__GI_abort () at abort.c:92
#2  0x00007fd14953952b in __libc_message (do_abort=<optimized out>, fmt=<optimized out>)
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/libc_fatal.c:189
#3  0x00007fd149542d76 in malloc_printerr (action=3, str=0x7fd14961b190 "free(): invalid next size (fast)",
    ptr=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:6283
#4  0x00007fd149547aac in *__GI___libc_free (mem=<optimized out>) at malloc.c:3738
#5  0x0000000000401098 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate (this=0x7fff792fc320, __p=0x1370010)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.7/ext/new_allocator.h:100
#6  0x0000000000400fc2 in std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_deallocate (this=0x7fff792fc320, __p=0x1370010,
    __n=10) at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:175
#7  0x0000000000400e3d in std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::~_Vector_base (this=0x7fff792fc320,
    __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:161
#8  0x0000000000400d28 in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::~vector (this=0x7fff792fc320, __in_chrg=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_vector.h:404
#9  0x0000000000400bbb in main () at ./main.cc:22
```

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing beyond the bounds of your vector causes undefined behaviour.  Anything could happen.  In your case, it looks like in case `(c)` that you overwrite some of the memory allocator's bookkeeping information, which causes a crash when your vector's destructor tries to free memory at the end of the function.